# Is it okay if I use cloudflare's and my web host's nameservers for my domain?

Tags: dns

Basically I have set three nameservers:

1. cloudflare-provided
2. cloudflare-provided
3. webhost provided

would this cause any issues? would domain addresses resolve correctly? will domain addresses resolve a third to each, or would it prioritize the top two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as many DNS servers as you like, a domain name will still be resolved correctly. They will answer the same: the domain names registered IP address. The only difference might be how fast changes are propagated to different DNS servers.

Also note that whatever DNS server *you* use is irrelevant for users of your web page or whatever you want to publish under that domain name. Users have their own configuration which you have no influence on whatsoever.

The order of resolution, so which server is queried when depends on your setup. Most systems offer different means of prioritizing queries. In general: if some server fails to resolve the domain name, then other servers from your list will be queried.

Comment: Yes, that answers it.. It's just that media temple would offer a slightly different zone file then cloudflare, and I just wanted to increase my margins of safety.

Comment: It definitely makes sense to configure more than a single DNS server, as a protection against a failure of that server. And certainly it makes sense to pick two fast ones on separate networks for redundancy. But that's about all the magic there is.